# Is there a way to see only questions related to my favourite tags?

Tags: support, tags

From time to time I middle click all my tags to open them in new tabs and go look for some questions that I might be able to answer. I know that outside of this tags it is almost impossible for me to give a nice answer to someone.

Is it possible to see only questions related to my favourite tags instead of going one by one in each browser tab??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `[tag] or [tag]` method. Like this:

```
http://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/apt+or+dpkg
```

You can use the unanswered tab:

```
http://askubuntu.com/unanswered/tagged?tab=mytags
```

You can use one of the [network wide filters](http://stackexchange.com/filters):

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This is a feature available on Stack Exchange's main page, if you go to "Filtered Questions" you can create filters for questions not just on Ask Ubuntu, but all stack Exchange sites. http://stackexchange.com/filters/6960/favorite-tags